# Ubuntu apt-get install error from nonexisting files

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, installation, apt-get

Couple of days ago I tried to install intellij. From that moment every time I want to install anything using command `sudo apt-get install` I get an error:

```
tar: /opt/ideaIC-*: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dpkg: error processing package intellij-idea-community (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 intellij-idea-community
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't install anything. I tried to delete all intellij files which I've found, but there is probably some script which tries to install those files.
Could you help me?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDlkW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line fixed the problem
`sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove intellij-idea-community`